# Android and WiFi Direct - Problems Connecting

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

So I have been working with WiFi Direct with quite some time and throughout it all I have been plagued with connection issues.  Since updating to 4.1 where there is no longer a hard button to turn WiFi Direct on and off, I seemingly always have inconsistencies with connecting. For my uses, I do not need to find peers, just connect to peers from stored device addresses from earlier interactions. Sometimes the devices will connect right away, other times the second device won't receive the invitation, and other times the first device will be stuck trying to send an invitation indefinitely. Below is my connect code, it's pretty bare so I am not sure what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you very much.

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
SlideMenuItem item = sideMenu.getItem(itemId);
config.deviceAddress = item.label;
config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;

if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
     progressDialog.dismiss();
 }
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Press back to cancel",
                "Connecting to :" + item.label, true, true);
manager.connect(channel, config, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connect failed. Retry.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

@Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Succesfully connected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Any Ideas? Any feedback would be great.

Comment: I know this is old but on the google bug tracker even google seems to acknowledge (or at least some devs do) that Wifi direct in android is somewhat broken.

Comment: I am having similar issues. Connections are very unreliable. Oftentimes, when trying to connect, the device will get stuck on "invitation sent"

Comment: We personally never figured out how to consistently getting it to work. I have not tried to use WiFi Direct since 4.2 though so the feature could be fixed by now.

Comment: On on 4.4 and it is still unreliable; gets stuck in the invitation process.  I do find that if is start the connection on a 2013 N7 it always works and if I start it on a 2012 N7, it pretty much always fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had 4.0 and 4.1 devices and as far as I can tell, 4.0 had the option to switch Wi-Fi Direct on where as in 4.1 it is always on. The reason people don't realise this is because Wi-Fi Direct on 4.0 required that regular Wifi was switched off. Later, in 4.1, having regular Wifi enabled is what enables 'always-on' Wi-Fi Direct.

So the TL;DR version: Switch on regular WiFi if you can't find a Wi-Fi Direct option.

Not 100% on this but I hope that it helps.

Comment: That helps a little, but WiFi direct still seems to be plagued by reliability issues.

Comment: Definitely. You'll find most of Google has my name in WiFi Direct comment sections trying to figure some of this stuff out. I'm honestly not sure whether Google/Android even maintain it anymore or whether they've given up.

Answer (score -8):

Why don't you use WiFi Shoot? You just turn on WiFi, and when you go to WiFi shoot it will automatically show you that WiFi direct is on. For sending files, just hold the file and select send. An option will appear, "WiFi Shoot". This app will send it through WiFi directly.

Comment: I have a feeling that jbaum30 was creating his own app.